# Choosing a committee with both distinct and non-distinct positions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A student organization holds meetings every week, with one chosen leader and two assistants to run the meeting efficiently. If there are 14 weeks in a semester, how many students must be in the organization to guarantee that they can have a different set of leaders/assistants at every meeting?

I tried to solve backwards like so:

1. Choose a leader from $N$ students.
2. Choose two assistants from $N-1$ students.
3. Multiply the results of 1 and 2 and set equal to 14.

This gives:
$$N \cdot \frac{(N-1)!}{2!(N-1-2)!} = 14$$

which results in $N=5$.

However, I feel like I may have over-counted in regards to having a distinct leader and then two non-distinct assistants. How do I make sure my assistants aren't being repeated?

Comment: One of the factors in the denominator of the "choose" function accounts for repeats.

Comment: I see, so I went about it correctly?

Comment: The $2!$ already accounts for the fact that for the assistants B, C and leader A the permutation ABC is the same as ACB. The $=$ in your equation should be $\ge$.

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me.